# Inner products on separable, infinite-dimensional $C^\star$ algebras, and "adjoints" of maps

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, adjoint-operators

Let $A$ and $B$ be two separable $C^\star$ algebras, and $\phi:A\to B$ a bounded linear map. A faithful state on a $C^\star$ algebra $A$ is a state such that for $a$ in $A$, $\phi(a^\star a)=0$ iff $a=0$. Every separable $C^\star$ algebra has a faithful state ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/19538/norbert) is an answer that discusses this). If $\phi$ is a faithful state on a $C^\star$ algebra $A$, then $\langle a,b \rangle _\phi=\phi(b^\star a)$ for all $a,b$ in $A$ yields an inner product on $A$, and thus induces a norm $\lVert a\rVert_\phi =\sqrt{\phi(a^\star a)}$. Of course, $A$ might not be Cauchy complete with respect to the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_\phi$, in which case we denote the completion of $A$ with respect to $\lVert \cdot \rVert_\phi$ as $L^2 _\phi (A)$. It is direct to see that when $A$ is finite-dimensional, it is in fact Cauchy complete with respect to $\lVert \cdot \rVert_\phi$, that is, $L^2 _\phi(A)$ and $A$ are isomorphic as linear spaces.

**My first question is**:
(1) For infinite dimensional separable $A$, does there always exist a faithful state $\phi$ such that $A$ is Cauchy complete with respect to $\lVert \cdot \rVert_\phi$? That is, $L^2 _\phi(A)$ and $A$ are isomorphic as linear spaces? If not, what are necessary and / or sufficient conditions that must be imposed on $A$ for this to hold true?

Now, let us consider finite dimensional $C^\star$ algebras $A,B$, with faithful states $\phi,\psi$. Let $\alpha:A\to B$ be a linear map (and hence bounded: $A,B$ being finite dimensional), we denote by the same symbol the corresponding linear map between $L^2 _\phi(A)$ and $L^2 _\psi(B)$ (which are isomorphic to $A,B$ respectively as linear spaces), and is also bounded (finite dimensional). Now, we denote by $\alpha^\star:L^2 _\psi(B)\to L^2 _\phi(A)$ the Hilbert space adjoint of $\alpha$, an denote by the same symbol the corresponding linear map between $B,A$.

**My second question is**:
(2) Given two separable infinite dimensional $C^\star$ algebras $A,B$, with separable states $\phi,\psi$, and a bounded linear map $\alpha:A\to B$, is it possible to define a *bounded* linear map $\alpha^\star:B\to A$, such that $\langle \alpha(a), b \rangle_\psi = \langle a, \alpha^\star(b) \rangle_\phi$ for all $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $B$? (I am looking for an answer even when $A\subsetneq L^2 _\phi(A)$, $B\subsetneq L^2 _\psi(B)$ as linear spaces).

**My attempts (unsuccessful)**:
For the first question, I tried out several (simple) examples of $C^\star$ algebras in infinite dimensions, like $C(\mathbb{T})$ (continuous functions on the unit circle, with the supremum norm, multiplication pointwise, and the involution given by complex conjugation), and $\ell^\infty$ (with involution given by the complex conjugation, multiplication entrywise), and a couple of similar examples. However, with the half a dozen faithful states I could cook up overall (for example, for $C(\mathbb{T})$, $f\mapsto\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_\mathbb{T} f d\mu$ with $\mu$ being the Lebesgue measure, and for $\ell^\infty$, $(x_n)_n \mapsto \sum ^{j=1} _{\infty} \frac{x_j}{2^j}$) and some others, all being different, in the sense of not being related by permutations, I failed to get a positive answer. But of course, this does not imply one way or the other given the question, other than perhaps saying that the answer might not be immediate. For the second question, I identified several problems: a bounded map $\alpha:A\to B$ might not even be bounded when we consider the $\lVert \cdot \rVert _\phi$, $\lVert \cdot \rVert _\psi$ norms on $A,B$ respectively, rather than the $C^\star$ norms: for example, considering $A=B\otimes_{min} B$, the multiplication map turned out to be unbounded in those norms, for the example of $\ell^\infty$ mentioned above. Even if we consider a case where it is bounded, it might not be Cauchy complete with respect to the norm of interest (for example, in the case of $C(\mathbb{T})$ mentioned above). The proof of the existence and uniqueness of the adjoint that I am familiar with, pivots around the Riesz Representation Theorem for bounded linear functionals on Hilbert spaces, which fails if either of the conditions of completeness or boundedness fail to hold (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark) respectively, for answers that discuss these).

**A little bit on my background, in case it relevant**: I studied, for my Masters' thesis, basics of $C^\star$ algebras, positive and completely positive maps, dilations, and related topics. However, I am not (yet) familiar with the theory of unbounded linear operators.

**Edit 1**:
The motivation behind these questions are the following: any finite dimensional $C^\star$ algebra, as a linear space, can be "given" a Hilbert space structure, albeit with a different norm. Still, as everything is finite dimensional, all linear operators on such spaces are bounded. Moreover, for every linear map between two finite-dimensional $C^\star$ algebras, one can define "adjoint" maps, unique for each Hilbert space structure. These "adjoint" maps are sometimes useful in the study of quantum groups and graphs (I think). I was wondering how these carried on to infinite dimensions, if they did at all.

**Edit 2**:
Actually, even in finite dimensions, $\alpha^\star$ very much depends on $\phi$ and $\psi$, and not just $A$ and $B$, so it is perhaps not possible to have a very general idea of $\alpha^\star$ that is useful as well. However, I provide an example: Let $B=M_n$ ($n\times n$ complex matrices), $\psi(\cdot)=\frac{1}{n}Tr(\cdot)$, $A=B\otimes B$, $\phi=\psi\otimes\psi$ then, with $m:M_n\otimes M_n \to M_n$, $E_{i,j}\otimes E_{k,l} \mapsto \delta_{j,k} E_{i,l}$, where $E_{i,j}$ denotes the matrix with $1$ at the $i,j$-th entry and zero everywhere else. Of course, $\{E_{i,j}\}_{i,j=1}^n$ is a basis of $M_n$, and we write $\otimes_{min}$ as $\otimes$ as everything is nuclear. Then, $m^\star:M_n\otimes M_n \to M_n$, $E_{i,j}\mapsto \sum_{k=1}^n E_{i,k}\otimes E_{k,j}$. This is *a* "comultiplication", with respect to the trace.

Comment: 1) Where are those questions coming from? 2) The map $\alpha^*$ for the finite dimensional case works because all norms are equivalent, right?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn
1) I added an edit at the end of the question which should explain the motivation
2) $\alpha$ is bounded in the $L^2 _\phi$ norm because all norms are equivalent in finite dimensions. The definition of $\alpha^\star$ is possible because of the Riesz Representation Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is no,  and here is the reason.

Note that the identity mapping
$$
  i:A\to L^2_\phi(A)
  $$
is continuous.  Thus, if  $A=L^2_\phi(A)$, the open mapping theorem
implies that $i$ is an isomorphism and hence $A$ is seen to be isomorphic$^{(1)}$ to a Hilbert space.   This would in turn imply
that every closed subspace of $A$ is  also isomorphic to some Hilbert space.

This said, choose some self adjoint element $a$ in $A$ with infinite spectrum (these exist in any infinite dimensional
$C^*$-algebra) and consider the closed $^*$-subalgebra  $C^*(a)\subseteq A$ generated by $a$.  It is well known that $C^*(a)$ is
isometrically isomorphic to $C_0(\sigma (a)\setminus\{0\})$, so we conclude that $C_0(\sigma (a)\setminus\{0\})$ is
isomorphic to some Hilbert space.

However it is a well known fact that $C_0(X)$ is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space for every infinite locally compact
space $X$.

---

$^{(1)}$ Two normed spaces $E$ and $F$ are said to be *isomorphic* if there exists a map $T:E\to F$ which is linear, bijective, continuous, and whose inverse is continuous.  If $T$ is moreover isometric, then we say that $E$ and $F$ are *isometrically isomorphic*.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering the first question. Any comments on the second? I have added the motivation in the edit I just added at the end of the question. Just a short comment on what you wrote: we need to consider an element $a$ with infinite spectrum, and such an element always exist in an infinite dimensional $C^\star$ algebra: I am familiar with this. However, $\sigma(a)$ is always compact. So, I think that we really don't need to write $C_0(\sigma(a)$, but $C(\sigma(a))$ would be good enough, right? Of course, they are the same thing here, and it is just a matter of notation.

Comment: I am sorry for using the wrong space,  which I have just corrected.  When $A$ is unital, the $C^*$-algebra generated by $\{1,a\}$ is isomorphic to
$C(\sigma (a))$, but in the absence of a unit we should instead consider $C^*(a)$, which is isomorphic to $C_0(\sigma (a)\setminus\{0\})$.  So far I have no idea about your second question but I'm thinking about it.

Comment: you wrote: "It is a well known fact that $C_0(X)$ is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space for every infinite locally compact space $X$". I know that they cannot be isomorphic as *Banach* spaces (that is, isometrically isomorphic), because the sup norm (the one for $C_0(X)$) doesn't satisfy the parallelogram identity. But the (first) question was, whether or not they can be isomorphic as *linear* spaces (norm not a factor of interest). I think that what we would need to prove here, is that there does not exist *any* norm on $C_0(X)$ that satisfies the parallelogram law.

Comment: Every vector space admits a norm satisfying the parallelogram law: just take a Hamel basis and define an inner product making that an orthonormal basis.  The contradiction I proposed, on the other hand, is related to the fact that there is no  linear map from $C_0(X)$ onto a Hilbert space which is bijective, continuous, and whose inverse is also continuous (that is, a linear isomorphism and at the same time a topological homeomorphism).

Comment: How is this any different than my answer together with the comment that I made every C*-algebra contains abelian C*-subalgebras?

Comment: @Ruy, "Every vector space admits a norm satisfying the parallelogram law: just take a Hamel basis and define an inner product making that an orthonormal basis." But is the vector space necessarily Cauchy complete with respect to this norm? That is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @Ruy, "The contradiction I proposed, on the other hand, is related to the fact that there is no linear map from $C_0(X)$ onto a Hilbert space which is bijective, continuous, and whose inverse is also continuous (that is, a linear isomorphism and at the same time a topological homeomorphism)." I think that this should also imply that even if there is a norm on $C_0(X)$ that makes it a Hilbert Space, that norm will not be topologically equivalent to the $C^\star$ norm. Am I correct?

Comment: In my second comment I was addressing your statement that "there does not exist any norm on $C_0(X)$ that satisfies the parallelogram law", so I didn't bother to make it complete.  But if you are interested I can show you a complete one as well.

Comment: @Ruy That would be great. Please let me know!

Comment: You are correct to say that "I think that this should also imply that even if there is a norm on $C_0(X)$ that makes it a Hilbert Space, that norm will not be topologically equivalent to the $C^*$norm".

Comment: I don't think a negative answer to the first question follows from the existence of a complete Hilbert norm on $C_0(X)$.  But it does from my answer.

Comment: @Ruy, " I don't think a negative answer to the first question follows from the existence of a complete Hilbert norm on $C_0(X)$" yes, I made a mistake, sorry (corrected it).
"But it does from my answer." Perhaps I am missing something here. I am not looking for an inner product that induces the sup norm on $C_0(X)$ (it doesn't exist, I know that, since the sup norm doesn't satisfy parallelogram law), but rather an inner-product induced norm on $C_0(X)$ with respect to which $C_0(X)$ is complete.

Comment: @ruy exactly what ujan said.

Comment: I think we're going in the wrong direction by insisting in this point, but OK, here we go.  The Hamel dimension of every separable infinite dimensional Banach space is equal to the cardinal number $\omega_1$ so they are all isomorphic as vector spaces.  We may then pick a linear isomorphism (no topology involved) $\phi:C_0(X)\to\ell^2$ and define on $C_0(X)$ the norm $|||f||| = \|\phi(f)\|_2$.  It then follows that $C_0(X)$ is a (complete) Hilbert space with this norm.

Comment: @Ruy, thanks for the edit in your answer, now I get it, how you show that the answer to the first question is false.

Comment: Well, it is a bit unfortunate that the discussion on the first question became so long, but I think your second question is a lot more interesting!  I don't have a clear idea of what $\alpha^*$ means, even for finite dimensional algebras!

Comment: @Ruy, thanks. It would be great to have an idea of how to go about for the second question. "I don't have a clear idea of what $\alpha^\star$ means, even for finite dimensional algebras!": I just added an edit ("Edit 2"), that gives an example.

Comment: Regarding question 2, I believe one should not worry so much about whether or not the algebras are complete, and instead focus on examples in which the adjoint $\alpha^*$ exists and try to understand what it means.  Here is such a situation: suppose $A$ is a sub-algebra of $B$ and let $\alpha$ be the inclusion of $A$ in $B$.  Also, suppose that  $\psi$ is a faithful trace on $B$, and let $\phi$ be its restriction to $A$.   Under this setup I believe that, should $\alpha^*$ exist, it must be a conditional expectation from $B$ to $A$!!!

Answer (score 1):

About your first question, the intuition says that this is probably very unlikely. The following counter example comes from the commutative world and asserts us that this is the case:

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. We consider the C*-algebra $A=C(X)$, which is abelian. Then by Riesz representation we have that
$$A^*\cong\{\text{complex Borel measures on }X\} $$
and therefore the set of states on $A$ is identified with the Borel probability measures on $X$, i.e.
$$S(A)\cong\text{Prob}(X):=\{\text{(positive) Borel probability measures on } X\} $$
Now the inner product induced from a state $\mu\in S(A)$ is $\langle-,-\rangle_\mu:C(X)\to\mathbb{C}$ given by
$$\langle f,g\rangle_\mu=\int_Xf\bar{g}d\mu$$
Note that such a state is faithful when the measure $\mu$ has full support, since if $\langle f,f\rangle_\mu=0$ then $\int_X|f|^2d\mu=0$ so $|f|=0$ a.e. thus $f=0$. Every compact space admits a probability measure with full support, so we have a counter example: we actually have that $C(X)$ is not complete with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\mu:=\sqrt{\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\mu}$. The completion is actually equal to the Hilbert space $L^2(X,\mu)$: to see this simply recall that $C(X)$ is dense in $\|\cdot\|_2$ in $L^2(X,\mu)$. Of course $C(X)$ is a much smaller space than $L^2(X,\mu)$. Actually this example is the reason behind the notation $L^2_\phi(A)$ you are using.

Finally, since you are looking for separable $C^*$-algebras specifically, simply restrict to metrizable compact Hausdorff spaces (as $C(X)$ is separable iff $X$ is metrizable, given that $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space).

Comment: Also this does not contradict your statements about finite dimensional $C^*$-algebras: the only finite dimensional, abelian $C^*$-algebras are finite copies of $\mathbb{C}$. I believe this also shows that you cannot formulate any interesting conditions for Q1 to have a nice answer, since any infinite dimensional C*-algebra contains some abelian C*-subalgebra.

Comment: Ops!  Your statement that $f=0$ a.e. implies that $f=0$ is false!  Think e.g. of a Dirac measure.

Comment: @Ruy, I was just going to say the same thing. I think it's not true that just any positive Borel probability measure would give us a faithful state. It would give us a state, true, but I don't think it would give us a faithful state. After all, if $X$ is compact, states on $X$ are in one-one correspondence with the Borel probability measures on $X$, right? So, it appears to me that even a non-faithful state would give us a Borel probability measure. And if we don't have a faithful state, we don't have an inner product, but just a positive (semi-definite) sesquilinear form.

Comment: It is true that probability measures correspond 1-1 with states.  Moreover a state is faithful iff the support of the corresponding measure is the whole space.

Comment: @Ruy yeah, okay, I had in mind measures with full support. Still my answer provides a counter example, since every compact hausdorff space admits a probability measure with full support. So particularily $C[0,1])$ and the lebesgue measure provide a counter example.

Comment: @UjanChakraborty I have added this detail in my post. This is a solid counter example.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn, I think your logic is a bit wrong.  The OP asks for the existence of a state such that $\|\cdot\|_\phi$ is complete and you provided one that is not.

Comment: @Ruy No, I provide an example of a C*-algebra such that any faithful state yields a norm under which the C*-algebra is not complete.

Comment: @Ruy mentioning the Lebesgue measure in the previous comment was unnecessary, I can give you that

Comment: @JustDroppedIn, I had already noted this example: I mentioned in my question, as an attempt, I looked at $C(\mathbb{T})$, with the faithful state being integration with respect to the normalized Lebesgue measure, and noted that it is not complete (completion yields $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, which I didn't mention there, though). But I already had (a lot of) counterexamples from my previous attempts (as I already mentioned in my question), and as the question was enquiring about an existence, these were not conclusive in any way.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn, Thank you very much for pointing out that in the commutative, unital case, it is nice to look at the problem through Borel probability measures with full support. The question is, then, does there exist such a measure that makes $C(X)$ complete with respect to the induced $L^2$ norm? This would perhaps be a nice way to attack the problem. Thanks, again!

Comment: OK, but I think you did not yet prove that $C(X)$ fails to be complete with the 2-norm associated to ANY measure of full support.

Comment: "OK, but I think you did not yet prove that () fails to be complete with the 2-norm associated to ANY measure of full support." - Yes, that remains to be proved, I think

Comment: The failure of the parallelogram law would imply that these spaces are not isometrically isomorphic, but they may still be linearly homeomorphic!

Comment: @Ruy Okay, my bad. Still. Just take any bounded, not continuous function that is measurable. This OBVIOUS existence proves that $C(X)$ is a proper subspace of $L^2$.

Comment: If the sup norm fails the parallelogram law, it could still be a Hilbert space in another norm.

Comment: "Just take any bounded, not continuous function that is measurable".  Now you've nailed it!

Comment: Why are you persisting so much on this? This was obvious all along. The only essential part of this ton of comments was that I forgot to include the full support assumption.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn, "Just take any bounded, not continuous function that is measurable." thank you very much. Just one thing: I apologize in advance if this is obvious: why should such a function always exist? For some measures, they obviously do, but I think we still need to show that given a compact topological space, for any Borel probability measure, there exist measurable functions that are not continuous. Is this obvious (I may be missing something). Please let me know.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn, I apologize if my comments appeared to be rude.  I was just following along the discussion and trying to get the record straight regarding a few things that came into play.